# Linear Change of Coordinates and Distortion of Length and Volume

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

Suppose we have $n$ spherical caps $S_{1,\beta_{1}},\ldots,S_{n,\beta_{n}}$ of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, defined by $S_{j,\beta_{j}}:=S^{n-1}\cap B(v_{j,\beta_{j}},\rho)$, where $B(v_{j,\beta_{j}},\rho)$ is the ball of radius $\rho$ centered at the unit vector $v_{j,\beta_{j}}$. Suppose we also know that $|w_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge w_{n}|\geq\theta>0$ for all $w_{j}\in S_{j,\beta_{j}}$; i.e. $|\det([w_{1},\ldots,w_{n}])|\geq\theta$. Consider now the transformation $T$ defined by $v_{j,\beta_{j}}\mapsto e_{j}$, for $j=1,\ldots,n$, where $e_{j}$ is the $j^{th}$ standard basis vector. Why does it follow from these assumptions that the distortion of length under $T$ is $\mathrm{Poly}(\theta^{-1})$?

I should add that my motivation for this question is a generalization of the multilinear Kakeya inequality (specifically Corollary 6 in L. Guth's [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4683v2.pdf). I start with $n$ caps $S_{1},\ldots,S_{n}\subset S$ satisfying $|v_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge v_{n}|\geq\theta$ for all $v_{j}\in S_{j}$. I cover each $S_{j}$ by finite overlapping caps $S_{j,\beta}$ of size of $\rho$. From Hadamard's inequality, I know that if $0<\rho\leq C_{n}\theta$, then $|w_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge w_{n}|\geq\theta/2$ for all $w_{j}\in S_{j,\beta_{j}}$. Throughout what I do below, I want the total number of caps $_{j,\beta_{j}}$ to be $\lesssim_{n,\delta}\mathrm{Poly}(\theta^{-1})$, where $\delta>0$ is some known parameter.

Fix $n$ caps $S_{1,\beta_{1}},\ldots,S_{n,\beta_{n}}$ with centers $v_{1,\beta_{1}},\ldots,v_{n,\beta_{n}}$, respectively. The estimate in my answer below tells us that if we chose our $\rho\leq C_{n}\delta \theta$, where $\delta>0$ is some known parameter, then when we change coordinates mapping the center of each $S_{j,\beta_{j}}$ to the standard basis vector $e_{j}$, the image of $S_{j,\beta_{j}}$ in the new coordinates will belong to a $\delta$-nbhd around $e_{j}$, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ denote the transformation defined by $Ae_{j}=v_{j}$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. First, I claim that $\|A\|=\|A\|_{op}\leq \sqrt{n}$. Indeed, for $x=\sum_{j}\lambda_{j}e_{j}$, we have

$$\|Ax\|\leq\sum_{j}|\lambda_{j}|\|Ae_{j}\|=\sum_{j}|\lambda_{j}|\leq\sqrt{n}(\sum_{j}|\lambda_{j}|^{2})^{1/2}$$

where we use the hypothesis that the $v_{j}$ are unit vectors and convexity.

By the SVD, w.l.o.g. we may assume that the matrix of $A$ relative to the standard basis is diagonal with entries $\sigma_{1},\ldots,\sigma_{n}$. Since $\|n^{-1/2}A\|\leq 1$, we have that $|n^{-1/2}\sigma_{j}|\leq 1$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. Whence,

$$\frac{\theta}{n^{n/2}}=\frac{|\sigma_{1}\cdots\sigma_{n}|}{n^{n/2}}\leq\frac{|\sigma_{j}|}{n^{1/2}}$$
for any $j=1,\ldots,n$. Therefore $|\sigma_{j}|\geq n^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\theta$, from which it follows that $\|T\|=\|A^{-1}\|\lesssim_{n}\theta^{-1}$.

Comment: I'll add this as an edit to the question (which it should be, rather than an answer). You might want to [register your account](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/regards-to-registering-and-unregistered-user-account), as it will make the site easier to use (as in, I get the impression it's harder/less clear how to edit a question from an unregistered account; I may be wrong).

Comment: @pjs36: Sorry, why is it inappropriate to post this as answer, which, assuming it is correct, it is?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the whole thing was an explanation of your motivation! I've rolled back my edit to the question.

Comment: @TravisJ: I believe so. If you take a look at the proof of Cor. 6 in the paper I linked to, I need to know that if $\rho=\rho(\delta,\theta^{-1})$ (Guth uses $\nu$ instead of $\theta$) is sufficiently small, then $S_{j}$ gets map to a $\delta$-spherical cap around the vector $e_{j}$, where $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$, for $\epsilon>0$ given. This tells me that if $\rho\lesssim_{n,\eps}\theta$, I'll get that. I need this quant. bound since I'm partitioning caps of size of $\sim 1$ into caps of size $\rho$ and I want the total number of caps to be $\lesssim_{n,\epsilon}\text{Poly}(\theta^{-1})$.

Comment: @TravisJ: I also need to look at the image of $1$-neighborhoods $T_{j,a}$ of lines with direction $v_{j}$ (or near $v_{j}$) under $T=A^{-1}$. More precisely, suppose $T_{j,a}$ has direction $v_{j}$. Then  $T_{j,a}$ gets mapped to $A^{-1}T_{j,a}$, which by our above result is contained in a $C_{n}\mathrm{Poly}(\theta^{-1})$-nbhd of the standard basis vector $e_{j}$. This type of estimate together with the one in my earlier comment allow me to apply Guth's Theorem 2 in the new coordinates.

Comment: @TravisJ: Do you see an error with my work? It wasn't clear to me from your comment that you did. I'll concede that it was not evident that my answer was indeed what I wanted, based on the original question statement.